# Tesseract page segmentation mode. How does it work?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I've looked everywhere and yes, including on Tesseract [official documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessapi/4.0.0/a01629.html#a338d4c8b5d497b5ec3e6e4269d8ac66a), but I just couldn't find out how does the page segmentation work? Nor was I able to find the source code, only the declaration of classes & enums.

Specifically, I am interesed in finding out how (the exact steps/ "science") the enum psm=PSM.SINGLE_COLUMN work. What it takes into considerations, how it's adjusted etc.
The reason I need this information is because I chose to implement an OCR application for my final underdrag thesis and my teacher won't accept a "it's an enum and it does things behind I don't know/understand, but it works" answer:)

Thanksss,